# Some questions on event handling in Progress-4GL

Tags: event-handling, openedge, progress-4gl

I have been asked to implement an event handler on a fill-in field in a *.w file (in case of <kbd>F5</kbd>, something should be done).

I started doing the following:

```
ON F5 OF particular_fill-in_Field
DO:
    ...
END.
```

This did not work, and later I realised there already was the following present in the source code:

Inside include-file:

```
&GLOBAL-DEFINE SEARCH-KEYBOARD "F5":u
&GLOBAL-DEFINE SEARCH-MOUSE MOUSE-SELECT-DBLCLICK
```

Inside *.w file:

```
ON {&SEARCH-KEYBOARD},{&SEARCH-MOUSE} OF particular_fill-in_Field
DO: 
...
END.
```

While checking the progress website, I found [following URL](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/index.html#page/dvref%2Fon-statement.html%23), explaining the `ON`-statement:

```
ON CHOOSE OF b_next, b_prev DO:
  IF SELF:LABEL = "Next" THEN
  ...
```

This leaves me with some questions:

1. When I added my `ON F5` line, there were two event handlers for the <kbd>F5</kbd> (`SEARCH-KEYBOARD`) event. Why did this even compile and as it compiled, why did it take the already existing line of code and not the one I added?
2. The example on the URL shows how to handle the same event on different widgets (you can use the `SELF` object to know which widget launches the event handler), but what about different events on one widget (like in my case, `ON {&SEARCH-KEYBOARD},{&SEARCH-MOUSE} OF ...`), can I know which event has been triggered, `SEARCH-KEYBOARD` or `SEARCH-MOUSE`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the notes of the documentation you pointed to:

> *A trigger defined with the ON statement remains in effect until one of the following occurs:
> *Another ON statement defines another trigger (or REVERT) for the same event and widget

So, if I'm reading this correctly, the **last** ON wins, so I'm guessing your ON came after the other ON.

You can use the [LABEL attribute](https://documentation.progress.com/output/ua/OpenEdge_latest/pdsoe/PLUGINS_ROOT/com.openedge.pdt.langref.help/rfi1424919926872.html) of the LAST-EVENT system handle to get the event.

**Edit by [Dominique](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279155/dominique) for reference purposes**

Example:

```
ON {&SEARCH-KEYBOARD},{&SEARCH-MOUSE} OF particular_fill-in_Field
DO: 
    MESSAGE "The launched event is [" LAST-EVENT:LABEL "]" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
    ...
END.
```